# Disable ion-searchbar in ionic 2/3

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I want to disable ion-searchbar in ionic 2/3 so that only search-bar shows but we can't type in anything. I added `"disabled = true"` but that's not working.

Can you suggest something?

Comment: take a look at this question in ionic forum maybe it could be of some help https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-set-ion-searchbar-to-disabled/81064/13

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to do this with DOM manipulation.Here's the code:
I created a function to disable the searchbar

```
 disable() {
const inputs: any = document.getElementById("input").getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
inputs[0].disabled=true;
    }
```

All you have to do now is ass an html ionsearch bar & give it the id input

```
 <ion-searchbar
id="input">
</ion-searchbar>
```

Here's a 
[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-dbkzgq?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
constructor(
        private renderer:Renderer) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        let input = this.searchBar.getElementRef().nativeElement.querySelector('input');
        this.renderer.setElementAttribute(input, 'disabled', 'true');
    }
```

The above code disables the ion-searchbar. You just need to add the following attribute to the searchbar.

```
 <ion-searchbar #input> </ion-searchbar>
```